# Nodelet multi-threading example

Tags: ros, multi-thread, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am finding a way to separate some heavy load process into some standalone threads so that I could get other callbacks in time using nodelet. I looked at the nodelet wiki page but it has few description about its multi-threading model and usage, so I am wondering where I could find such usage examples or projects already doing this?

BTW, is creating my own threads using boost inside a nodelet a bad idea?

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12395/nodelet-multi-threading-example/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2011-12-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The camera1394 nodelet is an example of using multiple threads: [source](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/abc1950a6925628acc7581cabc312741706b6e4c/src/nodes/nodelet.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2011-12-24**:
Thanks! This helped me a lot.